# Boost's Dijkstra's Algorithm Tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, dijkstra

I am having difficulty figuring out how to use Boost's Dijkstra's algorithm. I have gone over their example and documentation, but I still cannot understand how to use it.

[Boost's documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html]
[Example of Dijkstra: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp]

Can someone please offer a step by step explanation with code examples to show how to use Boost's Dijkstra's algorithm?
I am using Boost's adjacency_list for my graph, just as in the example link above. (adjacency_list: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html)

Comment: Post some examples of what you've tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: "..their example and documentation" - Whose example and documentation are you using?

Comment: @hatchet: I assume it's http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp

Comment: Just to be sure, you do fully understand Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: @hatchet I posted links to the example and documentation above.

Comment: @Bart I do understand Dijkstra's. I would just prefer to use a well-tested library as opposed to wrestling with the bugs on my own.

Comment: @user1563613: Once again, whats tripping you up? As a sidenote you could also use [Lemon](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) which imo feels more intuitive then `Boost.Graph` (but that might just be me)

Comment: @Grizzly I have successfully populated a boost::adjacency_list with vertices and edges, but I cannot make sense of how to use dijkstra's algorithm. 
1) In the example (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp) dijktra's is computed differently if `defined(BOOST_MSVC) && BOOST_MSVC <= 1300`. Why? And what exactly is the difference between the code under the `#if` as opposed to the `#else`? 
2) What is a property_map and why is it necessary?
3) What is a predecessor_map and why is it necessary?
4) What parameters does dijkstra_shortest_paths accept?

Comment: @user1563613: You might want to edit that into your question...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

About the questions in the comments:

1. According to the comment in the sourcecode of the example VC++ has some problems with the [named parameter mechanism used](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/doc/bgl_named_params.html). Therefore I'd assume that both branches do basically the same think with the VC++ version just being more verbose (I didn't dive into it long enough to be 100% sure though).
2. A `property_map` maps vertices/edges to additional data associated with the particular vertex/edge. E.g. the `weightmap` in the example associates a weight (travelling cost) with each edge.
3. The `predecessor_map` is used to record the paths for all vertices (for every vertex the predecessor on the path from the root is recorded). As for why it's needed: Well that information is something one often hopes to get out of the algorithm.
4. The parameters are clearly listed in the [description](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html). Note the two versions, one with named parameters and one without (the later being used in VC++).

now for a somewhat step by step of the example code given in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp) (note that I never actually used Boost.Graph, so this is no guarantees on correctness, also I only included the relevant parts and omitted the `#if` for VC++):

```
  const int num_nodes = 5;
  //names of graph nodes
  enum nodes { A, B, C, D, E };
  char name[] = "ABCDE";
  //edges of the graph
  Edge edge_array[] = { Edge(A, C), Edge(B, B), Edge(B, D), Edge(B, E),
    Edge(C, B), Edge(C, D), Edge(D, E), Edge(E, A), Edge(E, B)
  };
  //weights/travelling costs for the edges
  int weights[] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1 };
  int num_arcs = sizeof(edge_array) / sizeof(Edge);

  //graph created from the list of edges
  graph_t g(edge_array, edge_array + num_arcs, weights, num_nodes);
  //create the property_map from edges to weights
  property_map<graph_t, edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = get(edge_weight, g);

  //create vectors to store the predecessors (p) and the distances from the root (d)
  std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
  std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));
  //create a descriptor for the source node
  vertex_descriptor s = vertex(A, g);

  //evaluate dijkstra on graph g with source s, predecessor_map p and distance_map d
  //note that predecessor_map(..).distance_map(..) is a bgl_named_params<P, T, R>, so a named parameter
  dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s, predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));
```

As I mentioned in the comments personally I find [lemon](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/wiki/Documentation) more intuitive to use then Boost.Graph, so maybe you might want to give that a look instead

Comment: @user1563613: if you find an answer helpful the typical way of saying thank you would be accepting and/or upvoting it

Comment: Where does the predecessor_map come from?